# error compiling suphp

Tags: apache2, compiling

Trying to install `suphp`, from source.

But when I run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-apache-user=www-data --with-setid-mode=paranoid
make
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 

In file included from /usr/include/apache2/ap_config.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/include/apache2/httpd.h:44,
                 from mod_suphp.c:24:
/usr/include/apache2/ap_hooks.h:39:17: fatal error: apr.h: No such file or file directory 
 #include "apr.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Latest, 0.7.1 Downloaded from: www.suphp.org/Download.html
I'v checked multiply guides, but this [one](http://www.binarytides.com/install-suphp-ubuntu/)  is the one i'm currently following.

Comment: Do you have your machine configured in a specific language different than English?

Comment: Norwegian. (translated it, tanks for pointing it out)

Comment: Hey, I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12699896/1505348), it has the same error than you. I'm not pointing to a solution, but you may find something useful there.

Comment: tank you i'll parse the info in that post, to se if it can bring me an fix.

Comment: Also, tell us what version and from where did you get your suPHP version. And if anything, what guide are you following.

Comment: added it to the question